# Toggle UltiSnips

Tags: vimscript, plugin-ultisnips

I have this following mapping in my `.vimrc`

```
" Toggle search next with blink and without blink
let s:enabled = 0

function! NextMatchToggle()
    if s:enabled
        unmap <buffer> n
        unmap <buffer> N
        let s:enabled = 0
    else
        nnoremap <buffer> n nzvzz
        nnoremap <buffer> N Nzvzz
        let s:enabled = 1
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>nmt :call NextMatchToggle()<cr>
```

It helps me toggle between two different behaviours of `n` and `N`.

I want this similar thing with `UltiSnips`[https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips].

What I could do is to add two snippets with same string "describing" these snippets, and when I type this "describing" string followed by `<tab>` I will be asked which snippet I want to use, then I could choose which one to use. I don't want this, I want the same "describing" string to act differently at different times.

I am mainly going to use any solution to this problem (if exists) to `.tex` files. Here's an example, it may be dull, but it'll explain what I mean: I'm writing some maths sets, say `$SL(n, \mathbb{R}$`, but for some other `.tex` document I might want to write this same set like this- `$SL_n(\mathbb{R})$` (maybe I am a coauthor and the other author has already written it like this). But I want `slnr` to be the string "describing" both the snippets. That's why I wanted a mechanism to switch between these two. Could this be done some other way?

Comment: I don't think it's possible and I don't see why anyone would want such a behavior: a snippet is triggered when you write a string "describing" the snippet followed by a key to expand your snippet. For example, you could write `loop` to get a `for` loop template and `fun` to get a function template. Using the same "describing" string would completely defeat the purpose of a snippet. I believe that you are facing a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754), so you should tell us more in details what you are trying to do and maybe someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: @statox I am mainly going to use any solution to this problem (if exists) to `.tex` files. Here's an example, it may be dull, but it describes what I mean: I'm writing some maths sets, say $SL(n, \mathbb{R}$, but for some other `.tex` document I might want to write this same set like this- $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ (maybe I am a coauthor and the other author has already written it like this). But I want `slnr` to be the string "describing" both the snippets. That's why I wanted a mechanism to switch between these two. Could this be done some other way?

Comment: @user938271 As far as I know there isn't, it's just a `.tex` file. Do you think this kind of toggling is possible?